# Get product ids from specific product attributes values using SQL in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get product ids where product attributes `pa_color = 'Black'` and `pa_waterproof = 'Yes'`. But I have not succeeded yet.

This is my code:

```
global $wpdb;

$product_id = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT post_id 
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
    WHERE meta_key='pa_color' 
    AND meta_value='Black' 
    AND meta_key='pa_waterproof' 
    AND meta_value='Yes' 
" );
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** *(related to your comment)*

You are may be trying to get the **variable product ID instead** which is not the same thing.

Then you can use **normal product attribute taxonomy** and **term names** values *(or even term Ids or term slugs)*.

In this case try the following:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT p.ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr2 ON p.ID = tr2.object_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt2 ON tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t2 ON tt2.term_id = t2.term_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
    AND tt.taxonomy LIKE 'pa_color'
    AND t.name = 'Black'
    AND tt2.taxonomy LIKE 'pa_waterproof'
    AND t2.name = 'Yes'
");

// Raw output
echo '<pre>'; print_r($results); echo '</pre>';
```

Tested and works

---

**First answer.**

**Get product variation ids from specific product attribute values using SQL in Woocommerce**

In the data base the product attribute registered terms for product variations in the `post_meta` table are term slugs (not term names) and all product attributes `meta_key` start with `attribute_pa_` instead of `pa_`.

So it will be `attribute_pa_color = 'black'` and `attribute_pa_waterproof = 'yes'` instead.

Also you need to make a SQL query on `wp_posts` table for `product_variation` **post type** Joining 2 times the `wp_postmeta` table to query each product attribute.

So try:

```
global $wpdb;

$variation_id = $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product_variation'
    AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_pa_color'
    AND pm.meta_value = 'black'
    AND pm2.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_pa_waterproof'
    AND pm2.meta_value = 'yes'
");

// Output
echo $variation_id . '<br>';
```

Tested and works

---

Comment: i use the globals attributes so for that i use pa_xxx . so i need the id post for pm and pm2 .

SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts as p
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as pm ON p.ID = pm.???
INNER JOIN wp_terms as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.???
WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product'
AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
AND pm.taxonomy LIKE 'pa_color'
AND pm2.slug LIKE 'black'

Comment: Dont use code… use words instead to explain please.